# will moving the element using transform: translate property overlap the other elements which come in its way?

Tags: html, css

In the CSS code, `.two` overlaps `.one` in the output. If we remove the `translate` property on `.two`, we can see in the output that `.one` overlaps `.two` because it has a `translate` property.

Similarly if I add div `.three` with `translate` property such that it moves towards `.one` and `.two`, it would again overlap whatever element it comes across.

How does the stacking order work in such cases?

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.two {
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```